# How to check if a custom post type uses a custom template?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, templates

I have created this custom post type called `books`, and I already know I can select it with the condition tag `is_singular( 'books' );`.

But, is there a way to select with its custom template name, I mean `"Full Width"` like we do with pages : is_page_template( 'Full Width' ) ?

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Full Width
 * Template Post Type: books
 *
 */
?>
```

It would be very handy, because **I need a conditional logic which dissociates Custom Post Type and the same Custom Post Type when it uses a specific Template Name**.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I was wondering, was that `Full Width` as in `is_page_template( 'Full Width' )` just a typo in the question? And are you truly looking for a solution which checks against the `Template Name` value?

Comment: I mixed up this conditional tag with another that's why it didn't work. I was not digging in the right direction. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean "Full Width" like we do with pages : is_page_template( 'Full
> Width' ) ?

- [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) does *not* accept a `Template Name` value like `Full Width`, but instead, a *file name* such as `full-width.php` or `templates/full-width.php`.
- Secondly, `is_page_template()` can be used with *any post types* and not just Pages (`page` post type), so you can also use the function to check if your `books` post uses a specific template.
- You can also or alternatively use [`get_page_template_slug()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/) which is used internally by `is_page_template()`, like so, where the template resides within a theme sub-directory:

  ```php
  // Note: In the loop, you'd use get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() ).
  if ( is_singular( 'books' ) &&
      'templates/full-width.php' === get_page_template_slug()
  ) {
      // your code
  }
  ```